# How to have a SelectInput that does not filter and shows all variables?

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have the following shiny app - my goal is to have an option in my inputs that does not filter named "all". The problem is that I can't figure out how to code the "All" function. I can filter down to a specific country no problem, but when I select "All" I get a blank plot.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


data <- data.frame(Country = c("France", "Germany","England","Spain"),
                   Count = c(10,12,15,9))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot1", height = 250)),
      box(selectInput("Dropdown","Select Country", c(data$Country, "All"))
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(data %>% 
             filter(Country == input$Dropdown),
           aes(x=Country, y=Count)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Here is some code I have tried which does not work

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(data %>% 
             filter{if (input$Dropdown == "All") data
               else (Country == input$Dropdown)} ,
           aes(x=Country, y=Count)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not filter when it is "All".  Try this

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
    if (c("All") %in% input$Dropdown) df <- data
    else df <- data %>% filter(Country == input$Dropdown)
    ggplot(df, aes(x=Country, y=Count)) + 
      geom_bar(stat = "identity")
  })
```